# How to load the facebook authorization immediately?

Tags: facebook, redirect, authorization

I've read a few posts which are similar in nature to this one but the answer I've been seeking hasn't been in any so I'm hoping to address the question in a slightly different manner.

What I would like to do is this: Create a facebook tab application run from an iFrame that goes directly to the authorization page to get user permission to access their account.  Thus far the only solution I've been able to find is to have a page load (either blank or with a small message asking them to wait a moment) then use javascript to redirect the parent frame to the authorization page.  Both of the methods that I know of to redirect the page before loading it do not work because they can't redirect the parent frame (PHP header:location, HTML Meta refresh).  So my question is this:  Is there a way to make it so that when they click the tab link it takes them directly to the authorization screen?  Or are we stuck with loading a page (either blank or not), then redirecting using javascript?